React.useEffect is keep executing
React.useEffect is keep executing for every button click. Not sure why ? Someone can help ?
const Dropdown1 = ({
  selectedItems = [],
}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedItems);
  }, [selectedItems]);

  return (
    <Button
      className="button"
      onClick={() => setOpen((prev) => !prev)}
    >
      Select
    </Button>

  );
};

// Render
<Dropdown1 />


Because of this:
const Dropdown1 = ({ selectedItems = [] }) => {

The selectedItems value isn't state-driven, nor is it a prop received by the component:
<Dropdown1 />

The empty array is a default value for the function parameter.  And every time that function executes, it creates an empty array to satisfy that default parameter.  Each such array is a new instance, so it triggers the useEffect dependency.
Instead, supply an instance as a prop:
<Dropdown1 selectedItems={[]} />

In this case the value isn't being created by the function, but is being supplied to the function.  Since the parent component doesn't re-render, it's the same array reference and doesn't trigger the useEffect dependency.

Thanks @david, it is helpful. So, it means the functional component re-execute every time when its internal state is getting updated, right ?

Hi Rahul, Yes, it is correct. The functional component re-executed every time. It means, every render - the initial render as well the re-renders due to the changes in state, is just as invoking the function again. Therefore the argument to the function will be initialised newly on every call. As the argument has changed, the useEffect will also run as it depends on it.
